# How come std::atomic<double> isn't implemented when compiling with clang?

Tags: c++, c++11, double, stdatomic

Consider the following piece of code:

```cpp
#include <atomic>

int main(void) {
  std::atomic<double> aDouble;
  aDouble = 6.0;
}
```

G++ compiles it just fine while clang++ produces the following:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 Main.cpp 
/tmp/Main-d4f0fc.o: In function `std::atomic<double>::store(double, std::memory_order)':
Main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6atomicIdE5storeEdSt12memory_order[_ZNSt6atomicIdE5storeEdSt12memory_order]+0x31): undefined reference to `__atomic_store_8'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Do they not link against the same standard library?

Comment: Mostly clang uses libc++ while gcc uses libstdc++.

Comment: Therefore, if you are compiling with Clang on a system that only has the GCC standard library installed, you probably need to pass the `-lstdc++` flag to Clang.

Comment: Yes, `clang++ -std=c++11 -lstdc++ Main.cpp` does indeed compile the program. So it's a matter of `libc++` not having implemented the feature while `libstdc++` has it?

Comment: **use `clang++  -stdlib=libstdc++` or `clang++ -stdlib=libc++` to make sure you get headers compatible with the library you link**.  @5gon12eder: don't use `-lstdc++`.  You could (at least in theory) get breakage if a `libc++` header file has an inline definition of something that depends on libc++ internals, and it ends up getting called with a pointer to something produced by a non-inlined `libstdc++` function (or vice versa).  See https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html

Comment: BTW, **libc++ supports `std::atomic<double>` now**.  For x86, it compiles to the same asm as libstdc++, which unfortunately isn't very efficient https://godbolt.org/g/aCcnG5 (with clang4.0 or gcc7): See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055402/atomic-double-floating-point-or-sse-avx-vector-load-store-on-x86-64 for more.

Answer (score 3):

If `clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++` doesn't solve your problem, link with `-latomic` for the implementation of these functions.

Try to get your compiler to inline 8-byte and narrower atomics, though, because the library functions have potentially large downsides.

Beware that the library functions don't support a memory ordering weaker than `memory_order_seq_cst`, so they *always* use `mfence` on x86, even if the source used `relaxed`.

---

The 32-bit x86 version of `__atomic_store_8` is even worse: it uses `lock cmpxchg8b` instead of an SSE or x87 8-byte store.  This makes it work even if it's misaligned, but at a massive performance penalty.   It also has two redundant `lock or [esp], 0` instructions as extra barriers around loading its arguments from the stack.  (I'm looking at `/usr/lib32/libatomic.so.1.2.0` from gcc7.1.1 on Arch Linux.)

Ironically, current gcc -m32 (in C11 mode, not C++11) under-aligns `atomic_llong` inside a struct, but inlines `movq xmm` loads/stores, so it's not actually atomic.  (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65146#c4)

Current clang -m32 aligns `atomic_llong` to 8 bytes even inside structs (unlike regular `long long`, which the i386 System V ABI only aligns to 4B). The irony is that clang generates calls to the library functions, which uses a `lock cmpxchg8b` (https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33109) so it actually is atomic even with cache-line splits. ([Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624881/why-is-integer-assignment-on-a-naturally-aligned-variable-atomic)).

So clang is safe even if some gcc-compiled code passes it a pointer to a misaligned `_Atomic long long`.  But it disagrees with gcc about struct layout, so this can only help if it gets a pointer to the atomic variable directly, rather than the containing struct.

---

Related: [Atomic double floating point or SSE/AVX vector load/store on x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055402/atomic-double-floating-point-or-sse-avx-vector-load-store-on-x86-64)

Comment: FWIW, -latomic did help (ubuntu 17.04, clang 5.0.1 -m32, all gcc-multilib etc. installed).